# Redirect some content from sub-domain to different domain

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

Even though this is Wordpress related, the concept is far enough away to discuss here.

I have a subdomain: blog.bla.com
I have hundreds of posts on this sub-domain, and need to rewrite some of them over to a new domain: bla.com/newPosts

With .htaccess 301 Redirects my research on the topic shows that I should be able to simply say:

`Rewrite 301 "blog.bla.com/test/article" "bla.com/test/article`

but this doesn't work. The available (php) plugins for Wordpress also fail to transfer between sub-/domains.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Add this rules to the top of the blog.bla.com .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^test/article$  http://bla.com/test/article  [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^test/article2$ http://bla.com/test/article2 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^test/article3$ http://bla.com/test/article3 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: This, unfortunately does not work. Thank you for your response